# php mysqli escape string error in sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to escape fields posted from a form.  I can successfully insert into the SQL database by commenting out the code that escapes the string.

The error received is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"test\",\"0123456789\",\"test@test.com\",\"1\",\"1\",\"fgsdfdfndfndfndfndfndfn\' at line 1
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
$Name= $_POST['fullname'];
$Phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$inBuilding = $_POST['inbuilding'];
$floor = $_POST['floor'];
$inRoom = $_POST['inroom'];
$majorDescription = $_POST['majorcategory'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `problem`.`reports` (`Name`, `PhoneNumber`, `EmailAddress`, `inBuilding`, `inRoom`, `Description`, `MajorDescription`) VALUES (";
$query .= '"' . $Name. '","' . $Phone . '","' . $email . '","' . $inBuilding . '","' . $inRoom . '","' . $description . '","' . $majorDescription . '");';


$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $query);
```

I have also tried:

```
$query = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $query);
```

with the same error.

According to other examples on stack overflow I changed the INSERT INTO code to the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `problem`.`reports` (Name, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, inBuilding, inRoom, Description, MajorDescription) VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$email', '$inBuilding', '$inRoom', '$description', '$majorDescription')");
```

This code gave server 500 error.

MySQL is fully updated.

Any assistance appreciated!

MikeW's solution worked.  Also realized I was trying to escape the string before I had opened the database making `mysqli_real_escape_string` return null.  Connecting to the database first, (`$connect= new connect("server","user","password");`) solved this problem.  Hopefully this will help anyone else with the same problems.

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of your 'revised' `$query`: there's a close parenthesis that does not belong.

Comment: You really should be using mysqli_escape_string() on the variable itself, not on the entire query string. Additionally, SQL likes if you use a single quote `'` to wrap values, not a double quote `"`.

Comment: gotcha, you mean on each variable?  I did try that too with the same error.

Comment: Right, yes on each variable. But, I think the problem may be the use of the double quote marks.

Comment: I tried with my revised $query without the extra close parenthesis (thanks to josh) and received the same error above.  No more 500 error though

Comment: Just a  thought: what version of PHP are you using? Is it possible you have magic quotes turned on?

Comment: I currently have 5.3.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using single quotes, not double quotes. Also, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` should be called on each variable, not on the query as a whole. You should get something like this:

```
$Name= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['fullname']);
// more variables, similarly escaped.

$query = "INSERT INTO `problem`.`reports` (`Name`, `PhoneNumber`, `EmailAddress`, `inBuilding`, `inRoom`, `Description`, `MajorDescription`) VALUES (";
$query .= "'$Name','$Phone','$email','$inBuilding','$inRoom','$description','$majorDescription')";
```

However, for this sort of query you should consider using prepared statements.

Comment: @travesty3 In answer to your now deleted comment: it looks like the 'practically identical' answer has been extensively edited since I posted this. Your answer was two lines of text last time I looked.

Comment: Receiving a 500 error with the code you gave. Not sure why as I double checked and its virtually identical.

Comment: @user2210274 Then the problem may be somewhere else in your code. There should be a message in your server error log.

Comment: The error is because the closing paren at the end of the last line of code is unmatched. I deleted my comment because I didn't want to sound whiny on here, but it does bug me when people post an answer that has already been posted. Seems like a cheap way to steal rep. Yes, I edited my answer, but the original answer was the first three lines in my current answer, which is the only part of my answer that I was referring to as being nearly identical to yours. Yes, you added a (IMHO unvaluable) code sample and a suggestion to use prepared statements, but if it were me, I would've just commented.

Comment: @Travesty3 Thanks for the heads up on the syntax error - now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if MySQL works with double-quotes. You should use single-quotes. But the more glaring issue is that you need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on every variable, not the entire query string.

To simplify the problem, say your query was as follows:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (Name) VALUES ('". $_POST['name'] ."')";
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $query);
```

And then say I pass in a value, `Michael O'Connor`. What does your query become?

```
INSERT INTO tbl (Name) VALUES (\'Michael O\'Connor\')
```

Notice that not only did the `'` in the actual name get escaped, but the quotes to surround that name also got escaped. If you called `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the entire compiled query string, it has no way to distinguish a `'` in the value vs. the ones that are supposed to surround the value.

Comment: @user2210274: No, I didn't mean to point the finger at any particular person. But more or less to the anonymous downvoter. Downvotes with no explanation kinda irritate me, especially when my answer is accurate.

Comment: I do agree.  I was downvoted as well, I think my post is relevant if not novice.

Comment: upvoted as you helped explain how string escaping works